# How do I add a new row with percentage change values to an existing dataframe which is in a wide format?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using `Rstudio` and I have this existing dataframe, which is the result of the following `R` Codes:

```
merged <- rbind(trunc(actual_2017_df), trunc(predicted_2017_df))
rownames(merged) <- c("2017 (A)", "2017 (P)")
merged

>           Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun      
2017 (A)    1247    1406    1760    2198    1689    2098    
2017 (P)    1259    1187    1649    2090    1682    2056
```

I want to add a new row to this `dataframe`, which will basically calculate the percentage change between the values of 2017 (A) and 2017 (P) for each month.

Desired output:

```
   >        Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun      
2017 (A)    1247    1406    1760    2198    1689    2098    
2017 (P)    1259    1187    1649    2090    1682    2056
Error        1%     -16%     -6%     -5%      0%     -2%
```

The Error is calculated as follows for 'Jan':
(1259-1247)/1247 * 100

How can I create a new `dataframe` which includes this additional 'Error' row?

Note: I want my final results in zero decimal place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We loop through the columns with `lapply` (assuming it is a `data.frame`), get the `diff`, divide with the first element, `round`, `paste` with the `%` and `rbind`

```
rbind(merged, error = lapply(merged, function(x) paste0(100*round(diff(x)/x[1], 2), "%")))
#          Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun
#2017 (A) 1247 1406 1760 2198 1689 2098
#2017 (P) 1259 1187 1649 2090 1682 2056
#error      1% -16%  -6%  -5%   0%  -2%
```

---

Or convert to `matrix`, get the `diff`, divide by the first row, and `paste` as above

```
rbind(merged, error = paste0(100*round(diff(as.matrix(merged))/merged[1,], 2), "%"))
```

Comment: Spot on! Exactly what I needed. Thanks!